# Ground to L1 in 3-phase have almost 0 V potential

Tags: ground, safety, wiring, fault

I am in Peru and was helping check ground rod to line and neutral and see higher than one leg to ground voltage. This is at a plant with 3 phase power 220/440 volts. The local utility doesn’t provide steady power, with frequent sags and spikes and outages.

The issues is a ground rod being installed after 2 years to upgrade safety. We tested L1 to ground 2 volts, L2 to ground 368 volts, L3 to ground 368 volts, L1 to L2 368 volts, L1 to L3 368 volts, L2 to L3 368 volts. It appears ground and L1 are same. There is another commercial building 700 yards away with same issue.  The plant has had some electrical projects and even when main meter turned off and neutral disconnected workers have felt shocks.

What can cause this high a voltage at ground rod and not trip breakers or injuries?

Comment: Hi. Do you have the neutral line, too? What's the voltage of that line (compared to Earth rod, L1, L2 and L3)?

Comment: @Saadat I think Peru (from a google search) only uses 3 conductors for 3-phase. So it must be delta. See [here](https://www.generatorjoe.net/html/countrypwr.html). I think [@transistor's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/459444) covers what little I think I know about delta. But if his opinion holds water for Peru, then there's a problem with the system. There is something called 'corner-grounded' for 3 phase but *"Some low-voltage delta-connected systems have been grounded by grounding one line of the system, but this method has many disadvantages and is not recommended."*

Comment: Ditto what Periblepsis said. Google for "corner grounded delta." You'll get lots of hits,  and it sounds exactly like what you described.

Comment: Wow, I couldn't imagine in a system they would do such a thing! Technically, the neutral is imaginary, and if the load is balanced, no current would go to it. But I never saw a case in which the null current is completely zero for the whole users.

Comment: The neutral to line voltage is 220v to each phase.

Comment: @Dososo56 Can you confirm what voltage there is between neutral and ground then?

Comment: There are two 3 phase businesses on the same transformer and I was able to check both. 1st business Line to neutral 232, 226, 225. L1 to ground .55, L2 to ground 394, L3 to ground 396. Neutral to ground 230.